# Compare two hashes no matter symbols or strings, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, resque, string-to-symbol

I would like to compare two hashes and **forces** them to be equal:

- one with Symbols on keys **and** values
- the second with only strings.

e.g:

```
sym_hash = {:id=>58, :locale=>:"en-US"}
string_hash = {"id"=>58, "locale"=>"en-US"}
```

Try like this does not work:

```
> sym_hash == string_hash
=> false
```

I first tried to *symbolized* the `string_hash`:

```
> string_hash.deep_symbolize_keys
=> {:id=>58, :locale=>"en-US"}
```

But it is still false because `sym_hash` still has `:` in front of `locale` var.

Then I tried to *stringified* the `sym_hash`:

```
> sym_hash.with_indifferent_access
=> {"id"=>58, "locale"=>:"en-US"}
```

But when I test for equality it is still `false` for the same reasons.

**EDIT**

To answer many comments abouy *why* I wanted those hashes to be equal here, I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

I'm using [`Reque`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/resque/frames) to manage my jobs. Now I wanted to do a class to avoid having the same* job running, or being enqueued twice in the same time.

(*same*: for me the same job is a job having the same parameters, I would like to be able to enqueu twice the same jobs having differents ids for instance.)

For that I'm a using the plugin [`resque-status`](https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status), so far I'm able to know when a job is running or not. Beside, when I save the params using `set` I notice that the message written to `Redis`(because resque-status is using Redis to keep track of the job's status) is not properly saved with symbols.

Here is my class:

```
# This class is used to run thread-lock jobs with Resque.
#
# It will check if the job with the exact same params is already running or in the queue.
# If the job is not finished, it will returns false,
# otherwise, it will run and returns a the uuid of the job.
#
class JobLock
  def self.run(obj, params = {})
    # Get rid of completed jobs.
    Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.clear_completed
    # Check if your job is currently running or is in the queue.
    if !detect_processing_job(obj, params)
      job_uuid = obj.create(params)
      Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.set(job_uuid,
                                        job_name: obj.to_s,
                                        params: params)
      job_uuid
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def self.detect_processing_job(obj, params = {})
    Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.statuses.detect do |job|
      job['job_name'] == obj.to_s && compare_hashes(job['params'], params)
    end
  end

  def self.compare_hashes(string_hash, sym_hash)
    [sym_hash, string_hash].map do |h|
      h.map { |kv| kv.map(&:to_s) }.sort
    end.reduce :==
  end
end
```

And here how I can use it:

```
JobLock.run(MyAwesomeJob, id: 58, locale: :"en-US")
```

As you can see I used @mudasobwa's answer but I hope there is a easier way to achieve what I am trying to do!

Comment: these hashes ***are*** different

Comment: Yes, in this case I would like to modify them in order to make them similar

Comment: It's not a one-liner (unless you wrap it in a method), but you can loop over the hashes and compare the values based on their `to_s` method. I can provide a code sample if you want.

Comment: I would like a generic method that also can compare empty hashes. So I would prefer to not loop over each hashes. But please give it a try!

Comment: 1. From your example it would appear that for one hash (`sym_hash`), the keys are all symbols and no value is a string, and that for the other hash (`string_hash`) all keys are strings and no value is a symbol. Correct? (That's different than what you said.) 2. You want to know if the two hashes are equal if all the keys and values in `string_hash` that are strings are converted to symbols. Correct? 3. Please clarify what you mean by "forces them to be equal".

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I uptated my question to be more specific about what I am trying to achieve. For 1- How it is different that what I said? but yes you are right, I'm just failling to see my mistake ^^' To clarify, I would like to see is the content are the same in both hashes no matter symbols or strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
require 'set'

def sorta_equal?(sym_hash, str_hash)
  return false unless sym_hash.size == str_hash.size
  sym_hash.to_a.to_set == str_hash.map { |pair|
    pair.map { |o| o.is_a?(String) ? o.to_sym : o } }.to_set
end

sym_hash= {:id=>58, :locale=>:"en-US"}

sorta_equal?(sym_hash, {"id"=>58, "locale"=>"en-US"})           #=> true 
sorta_equal?(sym_hash, {"locale"=>"en-US", "id"=>58 })          #=> true 
sorta_equal?(sym_hash, {"id"=>58, "local"=>"en-US", "a"=>"b" }) #=> false 
sorta_equal?(sym_hash, {"id"=>58, "lacole"=>"en-US"})           #=> false 
sorta_equal?(sym_hash, {"id"=>58, [1,2,3]=>"en-US"})            #=> false 
sorta_equal?({}, {})                                            #=> true 

class A; end
a = A.new
sorta_equal?({:id=>a, :local=>:b}, {"id"=>a, "local"=>"b"})     #=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try to convert both hashes to JSON, and then compare them:

```
require 'json'
# => true 
sym_hash = {:id=>58, :locale=>:"en-US"}
# => {:id=>58, :locale=>:"en-US"} 
string_hash = {"id"=>58, "locale"=>"en-US"}
# => {"id"=>58, "locale"=>"en-US"} 
sym_hash.to_json == string_hash.to_json
# => true
```

Comment: This doesn't work when `string_hash = {"locale"=>"en-US", "id"=>58, }`, which should returns `false`, but should return `true`.

Comment: Correction: "...which returns false but should return true."

Comment: Better keep `string_hash` as is and convert `sym_hash` to json and then parse json. This way order of keys doesn't matter. Like this: `JSON.parse({:x=>1}.to_json) == {'x'=> 1}`.

Answer (score 1):

The version below works as PHP force-coercion equality:

```
[sym_hash, string_hash].map do |h|
  h.map { |kv| kv.map(&:to_s) }.sort
end.reduce :==
```

BTW, it’s not a one-liner only because I respect people with smartphones. On terminals of width 80 it’s a perfect oneliner.

To coerce only symbols to strings, preserving numerics to be distinguished from their string representations:

```
[sym_hash, string_hash].map do |h|
  h.map { |kv| kv.map { |e| e.is_a?(Symbol) ? e.to_s : e } }.sort
end.reduce :==
```

Comment: ty, yes I don't care about one-liner anyway. So it does not exist a method to transform automatically sym hashes keys **and** values?

Comment: I hope it does not exist.

Comment: you hope? why that? My problem here is that I put the first hash into reddis cache, but ofc reddis do not handle symbolic params. Maybe my problem is more of an XY one.

Comment: I _hope_ because Rails extensions basically kill the ability to write the code ourselves. Redis perfectly handles symbols AFAICT.

Comment: Nor does #1 work if `sym_hash` has a value for which to_s is not defined. I suggest #1 ↷️. –

Answer (score 1):

The value of `locale` in `sym_hash`  is a Symbol `:"en-US"`, 
while the value of `locale` in `string_hash` is a String. 
So they are not equal.

Now if you do:

```
sym_hash = {:id=>58, :locale=>"en-US"}
string_hash = {"id"=>58, "locale"=>"en-US"}
string_hash.symbolize_keys!
sym_hash == string_hash
=> true
```

Comment: Yes I am well aware of this problem, that is the whole point of my question actually :) I cannot rewrite the hashes on the fly because they are inside a function and accept a `params = {}` parameter.

Comment: I think than you need to loop through the hashes
`string_hash.values.map(&:to_s) == sym_hash.values.map(&:to_s)`

Or may you add the original code, so we could have a bit of context in order to find the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, to answer my problem I didn't need to force comparaison between hashes. I use `Marshal` to avoid the problem

```
class JobLock
  def self.run(obj, params = {})
    # Get rid of completed jobs.
    Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.clear_completed
    # Check if your job is currently running or is in the queue.
    if !detect_processing_job(obj, params)
      job_uuid = obj.create(params)
      Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.set(job_uuid,
                                        job_name: obj.to_s,
                                        params: Marshal.dump(params))
      job_uuid
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def self.detect_processing_job(obj, params = {})
    Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.statuses.detect do |job|
      job['job_name'] == obj.to_s && Marshal.load(job['params']) == params
    end
  end
end
```

Anyway, I let this question here because maybe it will help some people in the future...

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight deviation from the original question and an adaptation of some of the suggestions above. If the values can also be `String` / `Symbol` agnostic, then may I suggest:

```rb
  def flat_hash_to_sorted_string_hash(hash)
    hash.map { |key_value| key_value.map(&:to_s) }.sort.to_h.to_json
  end
```

this helper function can then be used to assert two hashes have effectively the same values without being type sensitive

```rb
assert_equal flat_hash_to_sorted_string_hash({ 'b' => 2, a: '1' }), flat_hash_to_sorted_string_hash({ b: '2', 'a' => 1 }) #=> true
```

Breakdown:

- by mapping a hash, the result is an array
- by making the keys / values a consistent type, we can leverage the `Array#sort` method without raising an error: `ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed`
- sorting gets the keys in a common order
- to_h return the object back to a hash

NOTE: this will not work for complex hashes with nested objects or for Float / Int, but as you can see the Int / String comparison works as well. This was inspired by the JSON approach already discussed, but without needing to use JSON, and felt like more than a comment was warranted here as this was the post I found the inspiration for the solution I was seeking.